# question of gradients syncronization of resnet example

Tags: ray

ray provide an [example](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example-resnet.html) for resnet distribution training.
but the gradients syncronization is strange:

1. sync up weigths
2. train each worker a specific steps independently.
3. go back to step 1.

**Is there any justification for this workflow?**

I think it's neither sync or async method.

Answer (score 0):

It's a slight generalization of normal synchronous SGD. If you train each worker for exactly one step in step 2, then it is regular batch SGD.

Comment: but, the default step is 200. so this method is likely have more noise then normal async method. because nomrally we train NN with data shuffling.